# how to protect method from concurrent invocation in reactor. Invoked by user via rest

Tags: project-reactor

I understand that synchronization is discouraged. Can someone show how to protect method from concurrent invocation, when paralel invocation comes from the users over rest? I can think of some of queue through which we serialize requests, but as beginner I wouldn't like to come up with crazy ideas. Can you show how this could look like done correctly? Also serializing is easy, but how about rejecting concurrent request while current one is already in progress?

Comment: Just trying to understand the use case here - do you want to set up a reactive chain where there can only ever be a single invocation in progress at once? That's a bit odd if so, as the whole point of a reactive chain is to enable massive concurrent scaling without eating up threads. Or is there just one part of the chain that has to have this limitation?

Comment: I'm new to reactive and did not see any real applications so I cannot copy know-how. Lets say, that you have bigger chains there and there. And then you have REST controller, where you can start/stop these reactive streams. But normally there would be some synchronization, so that you can start them just once. So if the source of data is JS, then maybe exhaustMap could be the correct operator, but I'd like to protect endpoint from multiple parallel users. Sure trivial synchronized would do the trick somehow, but I've read that this is no-way.

Comment: Afraid I'm still not understanding, sorry. The reactive stream is generally started, separately, with each request, and you can have many hundreds or thousands of the same stream executing simultaneously. The concept of a single reactive stream that you start just once is a bit of an odd one to me; that's what I can't quite get my head around.

Comment: OK. Lets be specific. I'm writing custom bridge from kafka to rest. So you have stream, which exists only on backend, on interaction with UI. It fetches data, does all processing needed, sends data further. You don't want to rebuild with each change. So in case of change, I'd like to stop the whole flow, change the settings, and re-run it. All dynamically. But I don't want to start it twice.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit of a niche use case - I think you'll have to synchronise to achieve that somewhere along the line (or use a library / built in class that manages that synchronisation for you of course, if you can find one that's relevant.) Others may be able to give a better solution though, it's not something I've come across before.